# WooCommerce PHP: Display data from custom meta created in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I recently created a custom field in functions.php to display a custom meta field in the Inventory tab for each product called barcode. What I now want to do is display the data onto my single product template using a PHP call. Here's first of all, the function to create the barcode data (which works):

```
function add_barcode(){
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_barcode',
            'label' => __( 'Barcode', 'your-plugin' ),
            'placeholder' => 'Scan Barcode',
            'desc_tip' => 'true',
            'description' => __( "Scan the product's barcode.", "your-plugin" )
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data','add_barcode');

function add_barcode_save( $product ){
    if( isset( $_POST['_barcode'] ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_barcode', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_barcode'] ) );
    } else {
        $product->delete_meta_data( '_barcode' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'add_barcode_save' );
```

Here's the PHP I'm trying to generate that data onto the page:

```
$product = wc_get_product();
echo '<strong>Barcode: </strong>' .$product->get_attribute( 'barcode' );
```

All I get here is a blank area after the HTML portion. So what function will allow me to display the barcode text?

Comment: You are trying to output attribute while you are saving post meta.  Replace $product->get_attribute( 'barcode' ) with get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_barcode', true);

Comment: `get_attribute` is for actual product _attributes_ - that is stuff like size for t-shirts, colors etc. What you have here is not a product attribute, you have simply stored a custom meta value. So you need to use the functionality to get meta data as well for this, and not `get_attribute`.